# Getting user char input for a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to find a way to get the users t/f answers into the array so that they can be checked against the key. I am now getting a never ending for loop. I am not sure how I could go about avoiding that.

```
public class TrueFalse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DecimalFormat mine = new DecimalFormat("##0.0");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Creates an array to store student answers
        char [][] studentAnswers = new char[8][11];
        System.out.println(" please enter T/F");
        for (int h = 0; h < studentAnswers[h].length; h++){
            for (int k = 0; k < studentAnswers.length; k++){
                studentAnswers[k][h] = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }

        //Answer Key that will be compared to student answers
        char [] keys = {'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F'};


        //Grading the user answers
        for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length; i++){
            //Grade for one student
            int score = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < studentAnswers[i].length; j++){
                if(studentAnswers[i][j] == keys[j])
                ++score;
            }

            double average = (double)score / studentAnswers.length  * 100; 

            System.out.println("Student number " + i + " score was: " + mine.format(average));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine so far.  How do you want to do this comparison, and what sort of output do you want?

Comment: I need to make sure that I can take the t/f input from the user and compares them to the key so I can take their correct answers and output the average.

Comment: The rest of my code is here: {for (int i = 0; i < studentAnswers.length; i++){
        //Grade for one student
        int correctAnswer = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < studentAnswers[i].length; j++){
            if(studentAnswers[i][j] == keys[j])
            correctAnswer++;
        }
        
        int average = (correctAnswer / 11) * 100; 
        
        System.out.println("Student number " + i + " score was: " + mine.format(average));}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following code to print your averages:

```
for (int i=0; i < studentAnswers[i].length; ++i) {
    int score = 0;
    for (int j=0; j < studentAnswers.length; ++j) {
        if (studentAnswers[j][i] == keys[j]) {
            ++score;
        }
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
    double average = (double)score / studentAnswers.length;
    System.out.println("Student number " + i + " score was: " + df.format(average));
}
```

Comment: The problem is more with having my for loop not coming to an end. The reason that I had the parameters set was to keep that from happening. I need to be able to enter at least 8 student answers to run against the key. I'm not sure where to go from here though

Comment: I ran the entire code (your OP along with this answer), and it seems to be working.

Comment: My full code is now up, I am not entirely sure what is different from your code and mine but I am not even making it past the original for loop

Comment: Are you aware that `input.next()` is going to sit there waiting until you enter a character?  You need to _input_ values for all your students.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that; however, does that mean I would have to input 88 values?

Comment: Well think about what you are asking me?  If you don't input the values, then whence will they come?  Yes, your current (working) code requires that you enter 88 values.  You could also read them in from an input file, but that is the subject of another question.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense what you are saying. When I ran it I didn't even think about that fact. I know it is off topic but how would you go about implement a way to re-ask the question for each row?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?  Are you asking how would redirect the code to request _every_ grade again?  Or, are you confused about how the input would work?  Java will prompt you for each of the 88 grades automatically.

Comment: The easiest way to put it is after entering 11 in the column to have the "please enter t/f to pop up again.